# Is there a word for lowering the importance of something by summarizing it?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

Often times someone will tell a long winded story, and then someone will reply with something like "So basically you just had a bad day."

Another, I think better example is when someone will talk a lot about existentialism, and then someone else will reply with "So basically 'to be or not to be, that is the question.'"

Or another example, someone will talk about Cuban-American relations after the cold war, and someone will reply with "So basically America plugged their ears and pretended Cuba didn't exist."

I don't think the word 'oversimplify' is good enough, because it can actually increase the importance of something. For example "So basically if you don't recycle, everyone will die of global warming."

Comment: Should I edit this question, to rectify its teenage language structure, or should I leave it alone to retain the reflection of the asker's level of English?

Comment: @BlessedGeek I don't think it's worth worrying about

Comment: `tl;dr` might be related (in written communication). It can lower the importance of the text even without an actual summary.

Comment: "Everyone will die" is still an oversimplification--"simpler" doesn't mean "less important."

Comment: @BlessedGeek "teenage language structure"?

Comment: Now is the time to Google for ["nothing buttery"](https://www.google.co.uk/#newwindow=1&q=nothing+buttery), it's not perfect, but I think you'll get my point. Technical term is apparently "metaphysical reductionism".

Comment: The last part of the question ("it can actually increase the importance of something") contradicts the title. Which should we respond to?

Comment: @Cat812 (And KyleStrand, I think, too) I suspect the last one is showing why "oversimplify" is *not* a good word choice -- hence is an example of something *other* than the intended meaning of the word he is looking for. So there's no contradiction with the title or the rest of the question text. The "it" in "it can actually increase the importance" refers to "oversimplify", not "the word I'm looking for".

Answer (score 24):

**Trivializing** or **trivialization** doesn't explicitly describe the act, but it describes the effect you're talking about.

This is in conjunction with WS2's answer: you **reduce** (or maybe **minimize**, as per Centaurus) the story to the point where it is **trivial**.

Comment: I'm starting to think that "guess the top-rated answer from the title of the question" would be a good game to play on this site. I got this one right!

Answer (score 12):

What you are talking about here is ***reduction***, as expressed in ***reductionism*** or ***reductionist***.

***Reduction*** is a perfectly valid process, not only in mathematics - reducing a mathematical argument to its simplest form - but in things such as philosophy etc.

But the examples you give are of things, which I would assert are ***perversely reductionist***.

The Oxford Dictionary Online does note that it is *often DEROGATORY*. Hence it may be possible to leave out the ***perversely***, above, and sufficient to say the arguments are ***reductionist***.

Comment: *Reductio ad absurdum* is the extreme example of this.

Comment: Plus of course [*reductio ad absurdum*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reductio_ad_absurdum) is a standard technique in critical thinking/reasoned argument.

Comment: @Robusto *Reductio ad absurdum* is certainly an example of a mathematical use of *reduction*. It does not imply perversity, so much as being a proof. You reduce the argument to a point where it is demonstrably absurd, and by so doing prove that the original statement is false.

Comment: @WS2: That's the original, technical meaning, but the term itself has gained a wider currency as a placeholder for any manifestation of that fallacy in practically any discipline.

Comment: @Robusto I agree with you. The point I was trying to make was that it is not necessarily used in the perverse sense of the examples in the OP's question. It is a valid and useful form of *reduction*. But *reductionism* (as mostly understood) is more the territory of the *Smart Alec*.

Comment: OK. Well, in any case, +1.

Answer (score 10):

The rhetorical device known as **bathos** is defined as

> an abrupt transition in style from the exalted to the commonplace,
>   producing a ludicrous effect.

[[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bathos)]

Comment: the only actual answer here

Comment: This also shows up as an (underused) adjective, "bathetic." Perhaps the best term (combining two answers) would be "bathetic reductionism," since bathos isn't *necesssarily* reductive, and reductionism isn't *necessarily* bathetic.

Comment: I think this is a very interesting answer but I have sure as the fiery hounds of Bathos never heard that word before. Is it even real?

Comment: @itcouldevenbeaboat Maybe try reading more highbrow criticism of lowbrow fiction.

Answer (score 9):

> **minimize** - to treat or describe (something) as smaller or less important than it is [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/minimize)

- "I don't mean to minimize his contributions, on the contrary."
- "During the interview, he tried to minimize his flaws."

> **minimize** - "to represent as having the least degree of importance, value, or size: minimized the magnitude of the crisis." [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/minimize)

Comment: Minimize for me already has the connotation that it's only for optimization, i.e. minimize costs. Also it doesn't address the simplification part of my question. Trivialize would work as well, and it doesn't have the connotation.

Comment: @jamesnicolas You're right, "minimize" has the connotation of optimizations, especially when it refers to costs. But it also applies to trying to treat what someone says as less important. (see definitions).

Comment: @jamesnicolas not necessarily. "Don't minimize what I'm saying" would be a valid response here, if less apt than "trivialize"

Answer (score 6):

How about 'cut down' ?

As in "he cut her speech down to a simplified version of several complex points"

Although this can have a wider meaning. But the words have both a specific meaning and a general hint of the negative aspects of reduction 
as in 'cut it out' or 'cut from the team'
and down as in lower or lesser in both senses.

Or else the more colloquial expression "dumbing down".

Although dumbing down does not always mean a shorter version , just one that is more accessible to a wider range of people including those without much intelligence!

Comment: "Cut Down" is great (with sayings like "cutting down to size" lurking in the background) probably the best on the list so far IMO. "Dumbing Down" is good, but it slights the person doing the dumbing down and implies that there is much more worth to the original statement. So, for me, at least, it doesn't imply the original statement is trivial - probably the opposite.

Comment: Also, more, colloquially "play down"

Answer (score 3):

This is an example of when someone takes the opportunity to

## downplay

Something someone else says

Answer (score 3):

- *to give short shrift*

Per [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/short_shrift):

> A quick rejection, especially one which is impolite and undertaken without proper consideration.

In fact, I actually like the definition that [Google puts at the top of the search page for the phrase](https://www.google.com/search?q=short%20shrift) even better:

> rapid and unsympathetic dismissal; curt treatment.

Merriam-Webster and OED, however, favor the older definition from which this meaning is derived:

> a brief space of time allowed for a criminal to make his confession before execution

<sup>([OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/178859?redirectedFrom=short+shrift#eid23080042))</sup>

> **1** : barely adequate time for confession before execution

<sup>([Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/short%20shrift))</sup>

Comment: Err, the other only actual answer here...

Comment: +1, with a note: The [Concise OED (2011)](https://books.google.com/books?id=sYScAQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA1334&ots=nWbFWuHV29&dq=%22rapid%20and%20unsympathetic%20dismissal%3B%20curt%20treatment%22&pg=PA1334#v=onepage&q=%22rapid%20and%20unsympathetic%20dismissal;%20curt%20treatment%22&f=false) gives your Google result as the primary definition and marks your OED definition as archaic.

Answer (score 1):

**Underplay** could work. 
One could also use **truncate** but it should be accompanied by an adjective such as

> a blunt truncation

or

> a dismissive truncation

Comment: Also (and probably more common, e.g. in the news): "downplay"

Comment: I'm also not sure "truncate" is appropriate. That means "to shorten," but in the sense of cutting them off. Maybe you retold the story to someone else, but left out the ending and thereby made the whole thing seem trivial -- you **truncated** the story -- but even then it too literally describes the restatement and connotes something different.

Answer (score 0):

**Condescend** con·de·scend \ˌkän-di-ˈsend\ verb -[MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/condescend)

> 1,a :  to descend to a less formal or dignified level

I believe the OP was looking for a retort (to an accusation of [superfluousness](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/unsuperfluousness)) along the lines of:

> Do not *condescend* to me that existentialism is simply 'to be or not to be'.

Answer (score -1):

I think a good word for doing something like that is 'minimizing'

Comment: Why do you think it's a good word? Could you provide an example where this term fits? I've heard of *minimizing a problem* and *a situation*, but not a long-winded story or somebody's introspective/political/philosophical discourse.

Comment: @Mari-LouA this answer isn't any different from any of the others, least of all mine (which is top-rated right now). It's the same idea: to **minimize** whatever the other person is saying.

Comment: Top rated? The post which has the highest number of votes is this [answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/229904/44619). I wish to add that I read your answer in the review queue and I was totally unaware that [Centaurus+](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/229893/44619) had already provided the same expression *and* given an explanation with clear references to back up his answer.

Comment: @Mari-LouA that's my answer

Answer (score -1):

It's a good starting point to look at **hyperbole** word and look at its opposites, that would be one of the words you need.
Per Wikipedia, "some opposites of hyperbole are *meiosis, litotes, understatement, lackluster, prosaic, dull and bathos*".
**Understatement** is a universal word, but depending on a context, **litotes**, **meiosis** and others could be used.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbole