# What is a word for making something seem not as bad as it actually is?

Tags: single-word-requests

**Some examples**:

- Instead of admitting that *I'm an alcoholic*, I just say *I had one too many drinks*.
- Instead of the bank admitting that *it has lots of loans that are in arrears and are likely to default*, it only says that *it has underperforming loans*.
- Instead of admitting that *they overeat*, they simply claim that *they have a strong appetite.*

Basically, I'm after a word for when a phrase is used that is not really a lie, but doesn't give the whole truth to make it sound more positive than it actually is. Usually when something should be dealt with, but it's kind of swept under the carpet by the misleading phrase.

Comment: Can you write an example sentence where the word or phrase would be used? The following is the strict rule of this community. *Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered*. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: [About single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info). Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Possible duplicate:  http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/229892/is-there-a-word-for-lowering-the-importance-of-something-by-summarizing-it

Comment: It's amazing how many good answers there are for this one.  It must be something people do constantly...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a word that means "a nicer word for a word"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/318670/is-there-a-word-that-means-a-nicer-word-for-a-word)

Comment: Public Relations

Comment: They *spun* the situation.

Comment: "mincing words", although usually used when commenting about somebody or something *else* rather than about oneself (as in your examples).

Comment: I'd also answer "meiosis", if I had the "reputation".

Comment: "Salesmanship" or "Marketing"

Comment: its an _undocumented_ feature.

Comment: @montelof or an *undocumented* worker

Comment: @montelof that's not what undocumented means in that context.

Comment: I was trying to reference the famous bug sugarcoating phrase: "It's not a bug; it's an undocumented feature"

Comment: @montelof I could see where you were going with that but technically it's beyond sugarcoating--it's actually turning a negative into a positive.  To put it in the context of the question it would be like a drunk insisting that he actually drives better after a few drinks.

Answer (score 186, accepted):

**Downplay**

> [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/downplay): to make (something) seem smaller or less important
>
> [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/downplay): to treat or speak of (something) so as to reduce emphasis on its importance, value, strength, etc.:
> *The press has downplayed the president's role in the negotiations.*

Comment: I'd probably use the expression "playing down" rather than "downplaying" as in "He was playing down the problem". I'm not sure if there's any real difference.

Comment: On the other hand, I find *downplaying the problem* to be smooth and natural, and *playing down the problem* to be very weird, because *downplay* is a single word, not a phrasal verb. The *down* part is not a preposition that would allow word reordering. For example, *outtakes* are short video clips of mistakes in filming. Would you ever break that apart into *takes out*? If the coach *sidelines* you, does he also *line side* you? If you are *hijacked*, are you *jacked high*? If someone *lowballs* your bid, were you also *balled low*?

Comment: @Richard Fwiw, I've never heard the expression "playing down" although I've heard the verb "downplay" many, many times (AmE, Western Pennsylvania)

Comment: @ErikE - No, but you might say that your car got 'jacked.

Comment: @Richard which could just as easily mean "messed up" or "destroyed" as "stolen while occupied". Not sure what your point is—I'm pretty sure you *downplay* things and don't *down play* them or *play down* things. The *shot up* of the situation is that we shouldn't *load over* our words. *Grown in* toenails really hurt. The boxer *cut uppered* his opponent. I am *lighting high* how odd it is to split prepositions out of single words that aren't phrasal verbs. I am *storm braining* for you! (Actually, you've given me a fun word game to play, thanks!) I hope I haven't done anything *handed under*.

Comment: @erike - Perhaps it's an idiom in *British* English; https://next.ft.com/content/5ec81170-4101-11e6-b22f-79eb4891c97d

Comment: @Richard that article is behind a paywall.

Comment: @ErikE - The FT headline is "*Andrea Leadsom seeks to play down pro-EU comments*". You can see similar content here; "*Hammond plays down PM’s ‘spectre of war’ speech"* http://www.thetimes.co.uk/article/hammond-seeks-to-play-down-pms-spectre-of-war-speech-jwnx9dfhz and here "*The Latest: Congressional Dems play down Clinton report*" - http://www.washingtontimes.com/news/2016/may/25/the-latest-state-dept-audit-faults-clinton-in-emai/

Comment: @Richard it's very *set upping* to know that the entire UK has gone mad and is perpetuating such a mistake founded on not knowing the difference between *downplay* and *down play*. (Hey, if that's how it's said over there, then no quibble from me, I just do find it *right down* jarring.)

Comment: @erike - The last quote is from the WaTi, an American rag.

Comment: @Richard Well down me blow! was being somewhat dramatic. I accept that "play down" is in somewhat wide circulation.

Comment: @ErikE - Don't you mean what some wide circulation?

Comment: @Richard That's the spirit!

Comment: euphemise may be?

Comment: *exactly* the response I came here to give.

Comment: British folks clearly don't understand English as well as Americans do ... "Play down"? Ha!

Comment: @Richard The headlines you gave are still using _down_ as a part of a phrasal verb, not as a preposition. The verb is either _downplay(-s/-ed)_ or _play(-s/-ed) down_, depending on your regional spelling preferences.

Comment: @J.Taylor - I've noticed that when sorely pressed, some Americans can actually speak and write a passable form of English.

Comment: @ErikE a speakers preference for "downplay" vs "play something down" is probably a function of the german influence in their community. people comfortable with german-derived compound verbs would convert "downplay the issue" to "play it down" like  they would convert "blow up the issue" to "blow it up" (not "blow up it")

Comment: @jamesturner I'm not so sure. I am quite comfortable with *downplay it*, and would probably notice and laugh at *play it down*. [I tend to notice things like this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58907/stop-if-you-feel-faint-or-pain) where something is wrong in language. *Play it down* feels wrong in the same way that *rpms* feels wrong—I just know something isn't right with it.

Comment: of course it's "playing down" ... not "downplay".

Answer (score 129):

[**Sugarcoat**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sugarcoat) - to make (something difficult or distasteful) appear more pleasant or acceptable.

> You can't **sugarcoat** your alcoholism this time MonkeyZeus, I'm taking the kids and leaving you! Also, what parent in their right mind would name their child with a name as awful as yours?!

Comment: I thought *sugarcoat* was only used to soften harsh messages to others.

Comment: @reinierpost I think *downplay* is much more apt, but I think there are reasons you might want to sugarcoat your message if someone is sensitive to their own problem.

Comment: @WayneWerner yes, but I wasn't aware that someone could sugarcoat their own problem.

Comment: @reinierpost It does seem weird in almost every way, except in relation to the title of the question :)

Comment: @reinierpost: You could say the bank in the OP's example was sugarcoating their loan exposure, or say that they're downplaying *the risk* of their loan exposure.  It's not a drop-in replacement for downplay.  I just speak English, I don't analyze it, so I can't tell you exactly why "downplay their loan exposure" doesn't seem to mean exactly the same thing.  (To me, "downplay their loan exposure" means de-emphasize the fact that there are bad loans, while "sugarcoat their loan exposure" means to give the impression that the loans aren't so bad, rather than avoiding the topic.)

Comment: @WayneWerner: ... cont'd: i.e. downplay could mean avoid the topic, while sugarcoat can't mean that.  It can mean using euphemisms or actual lies about what's actually going on.  However, I think sugarcoat also has other implications which don't fit the OP's use-case as well.  Part of this is just gut-feeling, and I can't think of anything specific to say to explain.

Comment: Equivalently, candycoat.

Comment: Another slight difference: *to sugarcoat* is an offensive move (part of an initiative to convince), *to downplay* is a defensive move (part of a response to uttered or anticipated criticism). As far as I've seen the terms used (but I'm not a native speaker, and I don't think my mother tongue has a term for either).

Answer (score 121):

A noun to express that could be *euphemism*:

> **Euphemism**: The substitution of an agreeable or inoffensive expression for one that may offend or suggest something unpleasant

Definition from the [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/euphemism).
The verb would be [*to euphemize*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/euphemize)

Comment: This.  It's worth noting that in the long term, euphemisms fail, as people learn they mean the same thing as the "offensive" term, and thereby become "offensive" themselves.  Consider how "crippled" was deemed offensive, and "handicapped" offered as the polite equivalent. As soon as people figured out it meant the same thing, it was swapped out for "disabled", which is now falling out of favor as well  (Some have offered "differently-abled" while others, who don't know how English works, insist on "persons with disabilities" as if it were significantly different from "disabled person"

Comment: @MontyHarder There are several names for this phenomenon; my favorite is the ["euphemism treadmill"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euphemism#Evolution)

Comment: @Sabre Mine, too, but I ran out of space to shoehorn it in. :)

Comment: When downvoting, a comment would be appreciated ! ;)

Comment: @MontyHarder Just a note on the "Persons with disabilities". This is done to put the reference to the "person" first in the phrase giving it a more personal focus and aiming to prevent addressing the disability over the person. Source: hours of corporate training.

Comment: @MontyHarder and now, * physically challenged*

Comment: My personal favourite is how "person of colour" is considered polite but "coloured person" is considered rude!

Comment: @gmiley Yes, as I said, this nonsense comes from people who don't understand how English works (normally putting adjectives before nouns) as opposed to other languages). It will make not one iota of difference in how people are actually treated (other than perhaps stoking resentment in those who want to get off the treadmill and get back to honest communication rather than such circumlocutions).

Comment: I don't agree with this answer. A euphemism is designed to express the same idea in more palatable terms. For instance, the asker's first example replaces "I'm an alcoholic" with "I had one too many drinks" - this changes the idea expressed (*alcoholism* is a chronic condition, *one too many drinks* is a single mistake even non-alcoholics make), so it's not a euphemism. A euphemism for this phrase would be something like "I'm not the type to refuse a drink", which still expresses an inability to stop drinking without using the often offensive term *alcoholic*.

Comment: That explains why I dislike euphemisms so strongly: they seem dishonest somehow.

Answer (score 68):

I'd say these are all [***understatements***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/understatement).

> The presentation of something as being smaller or less good or important than it really is:
> *a master of English understatement*
> [COUNT NOUN]: *to say I am delighted is an understatement*

Reference:
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/understatement

Comment: understate is a good word to answer this question.  Actually, even more generally, the "under-" prefix can be used with a large number of verbs.  e.g., underestimate, underperform, underwhelm...

Comment: The only counter to this is that *understate* can also apply to positives. The question is specifically about negatives, which means that in some contexts, *whitewash* could be more applicable.

Answer (score 62):

your examples sound like **whitewashing**

**whitewash** verb  white·wash \ˈhwīt-ˌwȯsh, ˈwīt-, -ˌwäsh\

> 1. to make (something) whiter by painting it with whitewash
> 2. **to prevent people from learning the truth about** (something bad, such as a dishonest, immoral, or illegal act or situation)

examples:

> 1. a book that tries to **whitewash** the country's past
> 2. refused to **whitewash** the governor's chronic disregard for the truth

source: [merriam-webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/whitewash)

further reading:

> [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitewashing_(censorship)) defines **whitewash** thusly:
>   "**to gloss over or cover up vices, crimes or scandals or to exonerate by
>   means of a perfunctory investigation or through biased presentation of
>   data**"

Comment: *Whitewash* means to remove or ignore negative connotations. The question is how to *understate* or *downplay* the negatives, (but see my comments there).

Comment: @Rich whitewashing is a complex activity that includes downplaying and removing both negative connotations and denotations. besides that, the examples from the question are clearly removing and/or ignoring negative facts from the situations, not simply softening the connotations to downplay the emotional impact.

Answer (score 58):

**Trivialize** — [ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/trivialize#trivialize__14)

> *verb (with object)*
>   Make (something) seem less important, significant, or complex than it really is.
>   *"the problem was either trivialized or ignored by teachers"*
>   *"As a result, the film seems to trivialize important events in Dutch history"*

Answer (score 37):

There are many good answers already in the list, but the one that jumped to my mind is not included, so I'll add it:

**Gloss over**

> to avoid considering something, such as an embarrassing mistake, to
>   make it seem not important, and to quickly continue talking about
>   something else
>   - Cambridge Dictionary

Answer (score 34):

One common idiom is **soft-pedal** from the action of pressing the "soft" pedal on a piano to reduce the volume.  The basic usage is to de-emphasize or minimize something that would otherwise seem quite important.

> **soft-pedal**: to treat or describe (something) as less important than it really is
>   http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/soft%E2%80%93pedal

Comment: Interesting, but incomplete to me without examples! They are a must for me.

Answer (score 30):

As a former counselor (addictions and otherwise), the word we used was "minimize", though this could be confusing to someone outside the field.  E.g. in a list of diagnostic criteria for a subject, we might write, "Mr. Smith minimized the consequences of his drinking."  This might mean that he said he had a "fender-bender" when in reality he totaled his car.

This usage traces its origins to Dr. Sigmund Freud, the father of psychiatry, as one of the types of defense mechanisms.

Comment: I do not think this usage is confined to any particular field. We might say: "The accused tried to minimize the seriousness of his offense."

Comment: But note that you had to use the qualifier "tried".  As a psychological defense mechanism, "minimizing" does not require that it be successful.

Comment: The qualifier "tried" is not absolutely necessary. For example I could say: "The use of such euphemisms tends to minimize the ugliness of war."

Comment: Although this word might actually be used in this way, this usage is somewhere between ambiguous and confusing, so please don't repeat it in new writing.  The core issue is that "minimize" means to cause an **actual** reduction, not just a reduced perception.

Answer (score 23):

## Spin

> In public relations, Spin is a form of propaganda, achieved through
>   providing a biased interpretation of an event or campaigning to
>   persuade public opinion in favor or against some organization or
>   public figure. While traditional public relations may also rely on
>   creative presentation of the facts, "spin" often implies the use of
>   disingenuous, deceptive, and highly manipulative tactics

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_(propaganda)

## Camouflage

Comment: Are you quoting someone here? If so, you should indicate that with a citation and probably a link.

Comment: Came to suggest "spin-doctor", but yes, spin alone works better.

Comment: upvoting for "spin", this is very common usage. Coming down from the PR/political sense, "spinning" is basically exactly what the OP is asking about -- "not quite lying" but bending the truth as much as is possible to make the subject matter seem more palatable to the audience.

Comment: Spin isn't unidirectional. You could spin a positive story about an opponent to seem more negative. "Sure, Bob attended the veteran's benefit dinner, but was he really there because he cares about vets, or just because he wanted to look good?"

Answer (score 18):

<sub>In case you need something more than single-words...</sub>

**Make light of** — [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/make+light+of)

> to treat something as if it were unimportant or humorous.
>   *"I wish you wouldn't make light of his problems. They're quite serious."*
>   *"I make light of my problems, and that makes me feel better."*

**Make little of** — [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/make+little+of)

> to minimize someone or something; to play someone or something down; to belittle someone or something.
>   *"John made little of my efforts to collect money for charity."*
>   *"The neighbors made little of John and thought he would amount to nothing."*

Answer (score 8):

If you're in the mood for a colourful idiom: A superficial fix for a more serious issue can be called **putting lipstick on the pig**.

Comment: +1. We could probably coin *lipsticking* for this, for short (if it doesn't already exist).

Comment: +1, There are a number of  other idioms for this, such as "polishing a turd".

Answer (score 7):

**Justify**, **Minimize**, and **Rationalize**

**Justify** has a secondary meaning of trying to defend oneself (especially when not warranted) such as *he tries to justify his actions*.

**Minimize** has a secondary meaning of representing the lowest possible amount or importance as in *he minimizes the importance of his actions*.

This term is used in psychology with the definition: a type of deception involving denial coupled with rationalisation in situations where complete denial is implausible. It is the opposite of exaggeration. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimisation_(psychology))

**Rationalize** has primary meaning which is to give causes which superficially seem reasonable but are unrelated, such as *he tries to rationalize his actions*.

In psychology, it has the following definition: a defense mechanism in which controversial behaviors or feelings are justified and explained in a seemingly rational or logical manner to avoid the true explanation, and are made consciously tolerable—or even admirable and superior—by plausible means. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rationalization_(psychology))

Answer (score 5):

**Ameliorate**

This word was the first that popped into my head, which dictionary.com defines as:

> to make or become better, more bearable, or more satisfactory; improve

dictionary.com made a distinction between ameliorate and:

**Alleviate**

> to make easier to endure; lessen; mitigate

Which it claims, means to actually improve the situation, rather than merely downplaying it or sugar coating it

Comment: ameliorating about actual improvements.

Answer (score 4):

**Massage** the truth

You can massage figures or facts to make them more amenable to your purposes. It sounds quite harmless.

Answer (score 4):

These sentences use **weasel words**.

From [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/weasel%20word) :

> :  a word used in order to evade or retreat from a direct or forthright statement or position

Or a longer definition from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weasel_word) :

> A **weasel word (also, anonymous authority)** is an informal term for words and phrases aimed at creating an impression that a specific and/or meaningful statement has been made, when only a vague or ambiguous claim has been communicated, enabling the specific meaning to be denied if the statement is challenged.
>
> To tergiversate is synonymous with the use of weasel words to avoid making an outright assertion. **Weasel words can imply meaning far beyond the claim actually being made.** Some weasel words may also have the effect of softening the force of **a potentially loaded or otherwise controversial statement through some form of understatement**, for example using detensifiers such as "somewhat" or "in most respects"....
>
> [...] Use of vague or ambiguous euphemisms (e.g., replacing "firing staff" with "streamlining the workforce")

Answer (score 3):

To be **in denial** is a slightly different take on your query that focuses somewhat more on the mental state of the person in question. But it directly applies to cases where, as you say in your question, "something should be dealt with, but it's kind of swept under the carpet by the misleading phrase."

> **[in denial](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/denial):** A condition in which someone will not admit that something sad, painful, etc., is true or real. — M-W

Example: "I think John is **in denial** about his alcohol problem. Whenever I try to talk to him about it, he just says that he has a few drinks every now and then."

It is used most often in cases where Person A believes there's a problem that should be dealt with and Person B (usually either the one who has the problem or one who's consent or participation is necessary in order to deal with the problem) is unwilling or unable to recognize that the problem is as severe as Person A believes it to be.

Answer (score 2):

**Sex up** is how they referred to fiddling Tony Blair's Iraq dossier. Apparently this has entered general parlance (although I've not heard it elsewhere).

> The implication is that no actual lying is taking place, but that spin is being placed on certain parts of the message.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexed_up

Comment: Sexing-up is "hyping up" to make something seem more powerful or more significant, like Blair did with his WMD "evidence". The questioner asked for I think the opposite i.e. a word when the "real thing" is being downplayed.

Comment: I've tweaked your idea and added a "sex down" answer !

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by MadMaardigan's **"sexed up"** [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/338195/131620), I suggest instead **"sexed down"**.

E.g. from the [BBC](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/programmes/panorama/3767247.stm)

> The government has been accused of **"sexing down"** a draft report on alcohol misuse to prevent the study damaging the case for extending pub opening hours.

E.g. from [businessinsider.com](http://www.businessinsider.com/r-uks-iraq-war-inquiry-report-delay-prompts-sexed-down-fears-2015-1?IR=T)

> LONDON (Reuters) - New delays to a major report into Britain's role in the Iraq War sparked fears on Wednesday that the public would conclude an inquiry's long-awaited findings had been **"sexed down"** to prevent criticism of former high-profile figures.

I can't find a respectable dictionary definition, but see the ["sexed up" answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/338195/131620) for the definition of original idiom.

Answer (score 1):

Note the term *sweet lemons* is used as a formal term in psycology as a defense mechanism.

Interestingly, it's hard to find via Google as the actual tree and Thai restaurants dominate the results. But [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=CWYAr7EzasQC&pg=PA372&lpg=PA372&dq=sweet+lemoning+psychology&source=bl&ots=qmPIKQ-I01&sig=es3vgHpgrjkBVqX09QPwIguQ2XU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwirocKCw_zNAhUszIMKHf58C0wQ6AEILDAG#v=onepage&q=sweet%20lemoning%20psychology&f=false) is a textbook showing what I remember.

Answer (score 1):

The word 'prevaricate' matches your definition exactly: telling the truth, strictly speaking, but by subtly distorting the facts to effectively lie.

Comment: Prevaricate does not convey the specific sense of reducing the importance of the thing discussed. You could just as well prevaricate to exaggerate the importance of a trivial thing.

Comment: I think this word, Prevaricate, is the most accurate answer to the original question. The meaning when you type it into google is, "speak or act in an evasive way". Perfect.

Answer (score 1):

#### Rose-Colored Glasses or Rose-Tinted Glasses

You could say that you are viewing a problem through [rose-colored glasses](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rose%E2%80%93colored%20glasses).

> optimistic eyes (views the world through rose-colored glasses)

There is a good discussion about the etymology of the phrase at the following link.

[Origin of "Rose tinted glasses"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/257566/origin-of-rose-tinted-glasses)

Answer (score 1):

A formal word for this is **circumlocution**, according to [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/circumlocution):

> (an example of) an indirect way of saying something, especially something unpleasant

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/circumlocution) also provides to example sentences, these are quoted below:

> "Economical with the truth" is a **circumlocution** for "lying".
>
> Politicians are experts in **circumlocution**.

Attribution: "Circumlocution Meaning in the Cambridge English Dictionary." Cambridge Dictionary. Accessed March 28, 2018. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/circumlocution.

Answer (score 0):

If it is more pro-actively made-up we can call it **romanticizing**

the free dictionary says [romanticize](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/romanticizing) is

> v.tr.
>
> To view or interpret romantically; make romantic.
>
> v.intr.
>
> To think in a romantic way.

[Google](https://www.google.com.sg/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=iVmOV8yxHOyq8wep5KOwBA&gws_rd=ssl#q=romanticizing) says it means:

> deal with or describe in an idealized or unrealistic fashion; make (something) seem better or more appealing than it really is.

with the sample sentence:

> "the tendency to romanticize non-industrial societies"

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/romanticize) also adds:

> (transitive) To interpret or view something in a romantic (unrealistic, idealized) manner.